# jquery disable/enable input/radio buttons

Tags: jquery, input, checkbox, radio-button

I disable the input/radio buttons on a form field.
When I try to enable them again with a button, that works fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/3Z6aQ/

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".control").toggle(

  function() {
      $('.target').removeAttr("disabled");
      $(this).addClass("checked");
  }, function() {
      $('.target').attr("disabled", true);
      $(this).removeClass("checked");
  });
});
```

But now, I try to enable this input buttons again with the "enter" button, but nothing happens here...can you please help me?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".control").toggle(

function() {
    $('.target').removeAttr("disabled");
    $(this).addClass("checked");
},
function() {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('.target').attr("disabled", true);
        $(this).removeClass("checked");
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f6s8U/

and that is what I tried in the last hour...but I have some problems with the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".control").toggle(

function() {
    $('.target').removeAttr("disabled");
    $(this).addClass("checked");
},

$('input').keypress(function(event) {

    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        $('.target').removeAttr("disabled");
        $(this).addClass("checked");
        alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox');
    }
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to your first fiddle, and then added a keypress event for your input. Since your only ever going to be able to trigger a keypress on the input when it's enabled, you can trigger a click on your 'checkbox' - which in turn, will disable the input:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".control").toggle(
    function () {
        $('.target').removeAttr("disabled");
        $(this).addClass("checked");
    }, function () {
        $('.target').attr("disabled", true);
        $(this).removeClass("checked");
    });

    $('input').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $('.control').click();
        }
    });
});
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/3Z6aQ/71/)

Answer (score 1):

Is it very unclear on what you are after, so it would be good if you could provide us with some more information.

But form what I gathered, this is what you are after:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".control").toggle(

    function () {
        $('.target').removeAttr("disabled");
        $(this).addClass("checked");
    }, function () {
        $('.target').attr("disabled", true);
        $(this).removeClass("checked");
    });
});
```

Also, make sure that you are using jQuery 1.7 since that is what is within your Fiddle.

[**FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8GSfQ/)